# project-based config: how to load plugins/colors from custom subdir of $PWD when doing `vim -u local/vimrc ...`?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, invocation

#### The Need, the Goal...

By "project-based config" I mean a project contained in a git repo that contains all the vim configuration -- vimrc and plugins and colorschemes -- right there in the repo.  In my case this is in the repo's `.config` directory.

So: `cd path/to/project && vi -u .config/vimrc some-script.py` should... somehow ...load all the plugins/colorschemes contained in that `.config` directory, ignoring the standard `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/*` config files.

#### Possible Strategies

1. Plugin manager:

   - vundle
   - pathogen
   - vim-plug
2. a plugin made for this

   - like https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc as a possibility
3. manual configuration

   - perhaps has multiple ways it could be achieved?
4. magic:

   - vim considers `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/` to always be siblings so if you do `vi -u path/to/config/vimrc` since vim is smart it will automatically  look for plugins inside `path/to/config/vim`
5. something else?

#### Problems

Well...

- #4 doesn't seem to exist.
- #2 doesn't match my criteria, as "an automatic way of sourcing vimrc from current directory" is a different use-case, I don't want automatic, it should require explicit intention by invoking `-u` or something comparable.
- #1: I've used pathogen for years, but I'm not sure if it's even capable of this.  I tried using vim-plug and could get that working in the same way pathogen works (with standard location of config files) but couldn't get it working for this use case.
- #3 I've spent hours reading `:h packages`, `:h packpath`, `:h runtimepath`, and trying to derive a solution from them but nothing yet works.  The trouble here is that `:h packages` is not clear about the distinction between `foo` and `foobar` in the context of a plugin that we find off Github (it describes unzipping individually zipped files).  Not a single plugin has I've seen has a `start` or `opt` directory, but it says to manually create that, though it's not explicitly clear about "where"... so just guess, and try every option!  I did this to no avail.  Additionally, `:h packpath` is not helpful and `:h packages` has no mention of it... but these two things might need to be used in tandem(?).

Answer (score 1):

There are two related options: `packpath` and `runtimepath`.

If you set `packpath` then all plugins sub-trees must reside under `pack/<bundle>/{start,opt}` to comply with `:h packages`.

If you set `runtimepath` directly then you must add *every separate plugin subtree* to `runtimepath` (and then also `runtime! plugin/**/*.vim` manually in case you have any). Also, you'll probably want to have `--noplugin` or `set noloadplugins` to disable auto expansion.

And last but not least, use valid VimScript only: only some commands accept arbitrary expressions. `set` is not one of them (consider that we write `set xyz=foobar` and NOT `set xyz="foobar"`).

Comment: What does `start` and `opt` mean?  Do I need to manually create those directories and then move the `plugin-name.vim` file into it?  I've read `:h packages` and that point is not explained.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage?  From inside this project directory I'm doing `vi -u .config/vimrc script.py` and I'm trying to put the packages in that directory's `.config/vim/packages` but putting in that local vimrc this line `set packpath=.config/vim/packages` doesn't do anything.  Plugins in that directory cannot be found when vim loads.

Comment: Plugins in the `start` directories load upon starting Vim.
Plugins in the `opt` directories only load when call by the `packadd` command.
See `:help packages` for all the details.

Comment: what's that have to do with `<bundle>`?

Comment: Everything is explained at `:h packages`. Read it from beginning to the very end as many times as it takes to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For a manual method, `packpath` can provide a solution (using only a single line of code in the vimrc file) with the following constraints:

`set packpath=.config/vim` will allow you to put plugins inside `.config/vim/pack/*/start/` (as well as `.config/vim/pack/*/opt/`) and this will work when invoked like `vi -u .config/vimrc scriptname.py`.

But when in a subdirectory of the project that `packpath` value won't work; if you're doing `vi -u ../.config/vimrc data.json` then the plugins will not load.  So you either need to:

- know the full path and hardcode the location like `set packpath=~/path/to/project/.config/vim`
- write some vimscript/etc to trace through parent directories to somehow identify the location (based on your project's unique structure) of the vim config, and then do `executure ':set packpath=' . yourVariable` since `set` can't take variables on its own.
- or, if you can accept this limitation, just always invoke vim from that project root

Once you've done `set packpath` in your project-specific vimrc, then you can add as many plugins you'd like...

`:h packages` says

> "When Vim starts up, after processing your .vimrc, it scans all directories in
> `packpath` for plugins under the "pack/*/start" directory."

So if `packpath=~/path/to/project/.config/vim` then you can:

- place plugins inside one big `...pack/bundle/start` directory like:

  - `~/path/to/project/.config/vim/pack/all-plugins/start/plugin-1-dir`
  - `~/path/to/project/.config/vim/pack/all-plugins/start/plugin-2-dir`
  - `~/path/to/project/.config/vim/pack/all-plugins/start/plugin-3-dir`
- or you can be more specific and do:

  - `~/path/to/project/.config/vim/pack/plugin1/start/plugin-1-dir`
  - `~/path/to/project/.config/vim/pack/plugin2/start/plugin-2-dir`
  - `~/path/to/project/.config/vim/pack/plugin3/start/plugin-3-dir`
- and if you don't want the plugin loaded right when Vim starts then you can use `opt` directory instead of `start` like `...pack/anything/opt/plugin-4-dir`.

`plugin-1-dir`, `plugin-2-dir` etc is just the name of the plugin from when you `git clone` it (or however you get it), and the file/directory structure that the module comes with can be used as-is without modification.